# Javascript implementation difference in days between 2 dates

Tags: javascript

I try to get the alert but for some reason i cant get the last alert to give me the diff from this code can anyone explain why i dont get the result? :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<input type="date" id="a"> 
<input type="date" id="b">
<input type="submit" id="c" onclick="getValue()">
<script>
    function getValue(){
        var startDate = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("b").value;

        var parts1 = startDate.split('-'); 
        var parts2 = endDate.split('-');

        var date1 = new Date(parts1);
        var date2 = new Date(parts2);

        var difference = Math.Abs(parts1 - parts2);
        difference = parseInt(difference / 86400000);

        alert(difference);
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) doesn't really expect an `Array` as an argument. And, `Array`s don't subtract very well (`parts1 - parts2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a simple mistake.Simply change the subtraction line with the one below.

```
var difference = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

As you are getting a direct date object in standard format so you should subtract those object directly. It'll simply give you the difference between the two dates.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/FQA9J/)

Comment: In your fiddle, that's not the only change you made to the original code. You changed `Math.Abs` to `parseInt` -- which should include a base argument of 10 -- and it returns negative numbers if `date2` is after `date1`.

Comment: The standard date object can be subtracted. And Math.Abs() was simply a typo. That doesn't make sense to give a down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you; I was merely pointing out that it wasn't the only change you made. Using `getTime` is much more explicit; when you subtract two `Date` objects, it's implicitly converted to milliseconds, so I thought it would be better to show that.

Comment: My mistake. Missed Math.abs(). Anyways, hope it's working now.OP had done everything, just made simple change.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with this code:

- `Date` doesn't expect an array, which is what `parts1` and `parts2` are. Just use `startDate` and `endDate`, which are date strings in a format that `Date` expects. It looks like the `Date` constructor does actually take an array and treats its arguments as if they were passed separately, but it's not necessary:

  ```
  > new Date(['2013', '10', '29']);
  Tue Oct 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
  ```
- `Math.Abs` doesn't exist; `Math.abs` is what you're looking for.
- Use `getTime()` on date objects to do math on them: `Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());`

[Here's a fiddle to show these fixes in context](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/d8cGg/).

Comment: See my comment @codeSpy's answer that you accepted as to why `getTime` is better, even if subtracting `Date` objects works in your browser.